# Spring 4 - Apache POI - Security: Error 403 al generar hoja Excel

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, apache-poi

Estoy en un proyecto con Spring MVC 4, y necesito generar un Excel con un conjunto de datos en pantalla. Para ello utilizo Apache POI para realizar la generación integrándolo con Spring. Sin embrago, cuando se ejecuta la descarga del archivo, obtengo un error 403. La aplicación incluye la seguridad de Spring y está configurada con Java y Annotations. He realizado la traza pero no llega a entrar ni siquiera en el controlador para gestionar el URL que se invoca al solicitar la descarga del Excel. Muestra la URL correcta, el controller está correctamente configurado... ¿Alguien se ha encontrado con algo parecido?

Comment: El error 403 se puede dar por diferentes cuestiones tal ves puedas compartir como lo estas implementando saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si ara el uso de la primavera de Seguridad con la configuración de Java, la protección CSRF está activado por defecto. En este contexto, si se hace una petición Ajax a un extremo REST utilizando el método POST, obtendrá una csrf perdido error token.

Para solucionar esto, hay dos opciones:

Opción 1: csrf Desactivar

```
@Override
protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Opción 2: Añadir csrf a la petición ajax. [Ver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax)

Comment: Se utiliza CSRF si, pero no Ajax. No es la idea desactivar CSRF.